# PhpStorm remote Xdebug issue

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

I'm trying to debug remote host from my local macbook, and face an issue - Xdebug doesn't stop at any breakpoint, including `xdebug_break()`.

I spend a lot of time by work around and try to fix it.

So my steps was:

- set `xdebug.remote_host` to my macbook IP, this fails and PhpStorm didn't get any connection and stacking on waiting for incoming requests
- change `xdebug.remote_port`, and find that 9001 somehow work for me (details below)
- turn on `xdebug.remote_autostart` - and this start debug process on very first line in my app, but still no stops on breakpoints
- setup SSH tunnel from local to server to 9001 port

More details:

- my OS: macOS 10.15.7
- OS on remote server: CentOS
- PhpStorm 2020.2.2

My php.ini config

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_start=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = on
```

My configuration in PhpStorm:

[image: CLI Interpreter config]

[image: Remote debug config]

[image: PHP debug config]

Any suggestions? waidw?

Comment: What does the link to validate the debugger configuration tell you?

Comment: 1) Enable, collect and share Xdebug log for the unsuccessful debug session. It will tell where Xdebug is trying to connect to and what the response is. 2) On your Servers, mappings -- why do you have the same remote path mapped twice? Double check the mappings. 3) It could be that the mapping is wrong: what will happen if you disable both "Force break at first line ..." options (last screenshot)?